# How to bind data from ASP.NET SQL to variables?

Tags: html, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a code like this:

```
public IActionResult ManageClass(ClassTable _table)
{
    int ClassId;
    string ClassName;
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionAdress);
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    command.Connection = connection;
    command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM ClassTable";
    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    connection.Close();
    return View();
}
```

`ManageClass.cshtml`:

```
@model List<StudentWeb.Models.ClassTable>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "View";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    string[] tableColumnHeader = new string[] { "Class ID", "Class Name" };
}

<p>Class name</p>
```

A total of 2 columns of data will come from this SQL query. I want to bind the data of the first of these incoming columns to the `ClassId` variable, and the second incoming data to the `ClassName`. How can I do that?

After binding the data to the variables, I will place it in the Table. It will be enough for you to show me how to bind the incoming data to the Variable. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

should be

```
public IActionResult ManageClass()
{
     var _table = new List<ClassTable>();
  
    using (var connection= new SqlConnection(connectionAdress)
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
          "SELECT * FROM ClassTable;", connection);

         connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

   if (reader.HasRows)
    {
     while (reader.Read())
     {
       var row = new ClassTable{
       ClassId= reader.GetInt32(0),
       ClassName=reader.GetString(1);
       };
       _table.Add(row);
        }
          }
      reader.Close();
   }    
  }
   return View(_table);
}
```

Bonus

you can create table

```
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Class Id</th>
                <th>Class Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr >
                    <td>@item.ClassId/td>
                    <td>@item.ClassName</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your nice answer. I got error: https://imgur.com/a/4SY72QJ

Comment: @EmirBolat You have to post your view, I don't what it there, but probably you will have to fix a view model - model List<ClassTable>

Comment: How can I show the `ClassName` on the page? I added the page codes by updating the topic.